# multiple projects in one solution

Tags: visual-studio

What is the use of multiple projects in one solution,as we can create multiple folders in one project itself,is there any security issues like if we have multiple projects provides good security or one project has less security
or Architect design(if so what is the actual problem to create multiple projects to overcome that problem)
what are the advantages of multiple projects in one solution

Thankyou

Comment: When we isolate the logic code with UI code we use multiple code so code can be used in other application too.

Comment: Possible dupicate of [In which cases does it make sense to have multiple projects in one solution?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5329879/in-which-cases-does-it-make-sense-to-have-multiple-projects-in-one-solution)

Comment: you might also want to use different languages in .net's roster, like c# for main part and c++/cli for native wrapper